# Terraform trying to overwrite my already made my gcp resource group, while trying to make another one

Tags: google-cloud-platform, automation, terraform

As the title says itself, I have created a gcp resource group via terraform script, when I want to make another, it try to overwrite my current resource group. I want to make another resource group while my previous one remains intact. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terraform files are not like scripts, they describe the end state.
Terraform normally loads all of the .tf and .tf.json files within a directory and expects each one to define a distinct set of configuration objects. If two files attempt to define the same object, Terraform returns an error.

For the stated requirement, you can follow one of these 3 ways -

(1) Create different resource blocks for different resources in your terraform
file.
(2) Use ‘count’ to create multiple resources in one block.
(3) Use different workspaces for different resource groups.